Does Ubuntu have obstacles to operating after an SSD swap?
My problem is that several keys have stopped working on the keyboard of my Ubuntu machine, likely Ubuntu 22.04.  I can't get past full disk de-encryption because my password needs some of the dead keys. I'm travelling so I don't have an address to receive a new keyboard even if the wait time were tolerable.
Will I have access to my data if I just move the SSD to a newer machine?  It's unlikely that I will be able to buy the same model and I would prefer a newer model anyway.  What problems am I likely to encounter?

Here's a resource that says that porting the physical drive to a different machine will probably work.  There is a caveat that it might not if the kernel has been customized.
Link

Ubuntu has started supporting TPM-based full-disk encryption from 23.10 onwards. If this is used, then for a new system, your encrypted drive is just a couple of boot/EFS partitions and a LUKS volume waiting to be reformatted.
